# How to display a table click on the link with in a same page?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd

i have two links.If i click one link its open a modal whether i click on the another link its open a table in the same page.

state = {
        visible: false,
        showTable:false
    }

```
showCourseModal = () => {
    this.setState({
        visible: true,
    });
}

onOk = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        visible: false,
    })

}

showStudentList = () => {
    this.setState({
        visible: true,
    })

}


render() {
    return (
        <div align="center">
        <a href="#" onClick={this.showCourseModal}>Course</a>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.showStudentList}>StudentList</a>
            <CourseModal
                visible={this.state.visible}
                onOk={this.onOk}
                onCancel={this.onCancel} />
                <StudentListtable showtable={this.state.showTable} data={data}/>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

if i click on the studenlist it will be displayed a StudentListTable in the same page.iam getting the data using student.json file.How to dispaly it?

```
         state = {
               showTable: this.props.showTable,
              }
            render() {

                return (
                    <div>
                        <div align="right">
                            <Button
                                type="primary">Update</Button>
                        </div>
                        <Table
                            dataSource={this.props.data}
                            showTable={this.props.showTable}
                            columns={columns}
                            pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}

                        />
                    </div>
                )
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using showTable. showStudentlist is updating visible

```
showStudentList = () => {
    this.setState({
        visible: true, <---Wrong, should be showTable: true
    })

}
```

Comment: Could you add the code for the StudentListtable as well?

Comment: iam adding the table component how to diplay the table click on a link with in the same page